# How to execute statement with set and select through PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a weird problem, when I use the query on phpMyAdmin, it works. But when I use using a PHP script it returns an error.

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

I tried to troubleshoot and discovered that the problem lies with the set statement.

This is my example code.

```
$sql = 'set @rank=0; select * from user;';
```

Answer (score 4):

First Run

```
set @rank=0;
```

it will store value of rank

then run:

```
select * from user;
```

In sort you need to run both queries separately .

set statement stores values. that can be used by next executing query,

like code below:

```php
$sql = "SET @id:=0";
$Executives = $DB->exec($sql); 
$sql = "SELECT @id:=@id+1 as id,pes.* FROM profile_executive_summary as pes where profile_id=".$pid; 
$Executives = $DB->fetchAssoc($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

See what `mysql_error` returns after you run `mysql_query('...')`. That might help. In general, `mysql_query` only permits one query. You can't separate them by newlines or semicolons. [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) will do it for you though.